# Можно ли расширить пространство на жестком диске за счет "облака"?

Tags: сервер, vps, облако

Есть *VPS* с Ubuntu 16.04, на жестком диске которой всего 5 ГБ.

Допустим у меня есть аккаунт в облачном сервисе (Яндекс.Диск, Dropbox, Google Drive, ...). Можно ли как-нибудь подключить облачное хранилище как жесткий диск или примонтировать в папку так, чтобы синхронизировалась только структура папок в облаке, а сами данные считывались/записывались бы напрямую из/в "облака"?

Comment: да, можно, но не все. Яндекс диск можно как [webrdive](https://habrahabr.ru/post/142067/)  (гуглить по davfs), google drive и дропбокс оффициально нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте сервис https://www.insynchq.com/ - он позволяет синхронизировать файлы между несколькими аккаунтами Google Drive и десктоп-клиентами (включая и Ubuntu). Видео о сервисе https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0nlU7E_xs8. Также посмотрите Syncplicity - он даёт больше места.

Comment: И почему мне кажется, что это реклама неведомого продукта за 30 дол?

Comment: нет. это не реклама. Мне самому нужен будет такой функционал через месяц... добавил в закладки, плюсанул... так как никто не отвечает, поделился тем, что нашел - кстати здесь пишут, что есть бесплатная версия, которая имеет только ряд ограничений http://www.livebusiness.ru/tool/954/

Comment: он предоставляет 1гб бесплатно для одного акаунта, но вы же можете создать несколько аккаунтов....